# No more anti-aliased fonts in cygwin xterm?

Tags: fonts, cygwin, xterm

I just recently updated my cygwin/xterm installation, and all of a sudden I don't have any more AA fonts in x-term. gVim works perfectly:

[image: screenshot]

I have absolutely no idea what's changed or how to fix this! I'm using XMing for my X-Server, on Windows XP Pro.

Here's my .Xdefaults file (which used to work perfectly, btw):

```
XTerm*faceName: Anonymous Pro
XTerm*faceSize: 14
XTerm*vt100*geometry: 180x65+10+10
XTerm*saveLines: 5000
XTerm*foreground: white
XTerm*background: black
XTerm*toolBar: false
XTerm*termName: xterm-256color
XTerm*scrollBar: true
XTerm*rightScrollBar: True
XTerm*scrollBarBorder: 2
!XTerm*Scrollbar*background: white
!XTerm*Scrollbar*foreground: black
!XTerm*Scrollbar*thickness: 12
XTerm*cursorBlink: true
XTerm*cursorOffTime: 300
XTerm*cursorOnTime: 300

Xcursor.theme: DMZ-Black
```